# Argument grabbing all ID's from Array

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm making a moviefilter website for school. Now the last part is that I need to link the imdbID from my array to the movie posters on the screen. I made the links, the filter mechanics work but when I click on a poster all the ID's of that filter are being added to the end. Not just one.

My teacher says I can forEach trough the movieArray array and write everything I need in that loop. Can someone help me or look at my code what I'm doing wrong. I wrote 2 seperate functions now to create the arguments needed.

My code:

```
const addMoviesToDom = function (movieArray) {
    const movieList = document.querySelector("#movielist");
    movieList.innerHTML = "";

    const moviePoster = movieArray.map(item => {
        return item.Poster;
    });
    const imdbId = movieArray.map(item => {
        return item.imdbID;
    })

    moviePoster.forEach(element => {
        let newLi = document.createElement("li");
        let newLink = document.createElement("a");
        let images = document.createElement("img");
        images.src = element;
        newLink.setAttribute("href", "https://www.imdb.com/title/" + imdbId);
        newLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        newLi.append(newLink);
        newLink.append(images);
        movieList.appendChild(newLi);
    })
};
addMoviesToDom(movies);
```

Thanks in advance, hopefully you guys understand what I'm trying to explain, this is all pretty new for me.

Comment: It would be great if you provide some sample input and output data  to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imdbId` is an array of all the IDs. When you concatenate that to `"https://www.imdb.com/title/"` it's turned into a string, which joins all the IDs with a `,` delimiter. So you're not setting the `href` to just the ID corresponding to the current `moviePoster` element.

You need to index the array to get the correct ID. `forEach` provides the array index as the second argument to the callback function, so you can change `element =>` to `(element, i) =>`, and then use `imdbId[i]`.

But a simpler way would be to skip creating the `moviePoster` and `imdbId` arrays, and just create all the elements from `movieArray`.

```js
const addMoviesToDom = function(movieArray) {
  const movieList = document.querySelector("#movielist");
  movieList.innerHTML = "";

  movieArray.forEach(element => {
    let newLi = document.createElement("li");
    let newLink = document.createElement("a");
    let images = document.createElement("img");
    images.src = element.Poster;
    newLink.setAttribute("href", "https://www.imdb.com/title/" + element.imdbId);
    newLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    newLi.append(newLink);
    newLink.append(images);
    movieList.appendChild(newLi);
  })
};
addMoviesToDom(movies);
```

Comment: Many many many thanks! You guys help me out a lot!